# I am trying to calculate PSD using scipy.signal.welch(x, fs=1.0, window='hann', nperseg=None, noverlap=None)

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I should have overlap of 50%,
noverlap
Number of points to overlap between segments. If None, noverlap = nperseg // 2. Defaults to None.

but i am confused here as noverlap=window//2 is considered as 0% overlapping i.e. None.

Comment: See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: `noverlap = window // 2` means there are `window // 2` overlapping points between one segment and the next, not 0% overlap. What prompted your question? Are you getting an unexpected output?